# Custom JSP Search Empty?

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-ide

I'm creating a new Hook in Liferay + Eclipse & I cannot find any of the Source JSP files under the "Select Liferay Portal JSP" Window - basically I can't search any of the JSPs that exist in Liferay, the only thing that shows up is index.jsp.

So far I've tried

- Uninstalling/Reinstalling Liferay ID
- Installing a new Plugins SDK
- Creating a new project
- Creating a new Eclipse workspace
- Deleting and re-adding a Liferay Plugin API to the build path

Nothing so far has worked - Has anyone had this issue before?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These JSP suggestions would come from a connected Liferay server - you'll need more than just the SDK (because it doesn't contain all of Liferay's JSPs.

So: Create a Liferay server runtime (point to a tomcat bundle) and IDE will find the JSPs

Comment: I had a standalone server installed that I pointed my project too, no jsps showed up. I downloaded the latest bundle and made it my targeted runtime & my JSPs returned. Any idea why this might be the case?